# CodeBlocks Autocompletion for Local Variables

Tags: c++, autocomplete, codeblocks, local-variables

I am using `Code::Blocks` **12.11** on Windows 8.

I have created a new `CPP` file and declared a class inside it. The main function is also located in this `CPP` file.

Now, while I do get auto-completion option for built-int items, such as `include`, but I don't get auto-completion for local variables.

How can I enable this?

Comment: Have you followed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749769/auto-complete-in-codeblocks)?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: No, maybe a good place to look for solution. Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to suggest clang complete, but I am not sure the plugin is actually alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue with CodeBlocks. The solution lies in answers to questions [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749769/auto-complete-in-codeblocks) .