# C++ Code::Blocks Autocomplete Not Working

Tags: c++, autocomplete, codeblocks

I just recently started learning C++ with Code::Blocks. When I first started using it, the autocomplete worked fine, but now it doesn't for some reason. What I mean by autocomplete is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int test;
}
```

If I were to type "te" (without the quotes), I wouldn't get a box that has the name of my variable in it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749769/auto-complete-in-codeblocks/   ? If not then please update question saying that you tried "Reparse project" etc. and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 14):

Disabling SmartSense (settings/editor/code completion) can resolve the problem.
With SmartSense enabled (default) code completion work partially.

Comment: can confirm that disabling smartsense enabled code-completion

Comment: I wonder why this is enabled by default, if it destroys half of the reason to use an IDE.

Comment: I am using Code blocks version 16.01. I don't have the option `SmartSense` in the mentioned area. And I can't solve my problem.  :(

Answer (score 2):

In the Editor settings, change the value of `autolaunch after typing # letters` from 3 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Check settings. 
Settings > Editor > General Settings > Editor Settings > Code Completion > Check [Code Completion]

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be good to know that for some versions, you need to close your `Code::Blocks` program and open it again so these changes of settings become effective.

Answer (score 0):

changing maximum allowed parser per project to 2 worked for me,go to setting>editor>code completion

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that using new C++ function header style will broke the code completion in code::blocks IDE.

The solution to recovery broken code completion is to use only the old C++ function header declaration.

```
// new function declaration
auto f() -> void; // will not work with cb cc
// classic function declaration
void f(void); // will work
```